# Fetch user details based on userId which is referenced field in userDetails table

Tags: mongodb

Database: MongoDB
Backend: Node.js

There are two tables in the database: User and userDetails. ObjectId in User table has been used as a reference in userDetails table as userId. Now based on this userId I want to display userDetails.

I have tried to make a function and tried to test that in postman but I get null data. When I test this function in api testing tool postman, I don't get any user Details.  I am not able to understand why I am not getting any data.

Here is the function:

```
  function getUserDetailByUserId(req, res) {
    userDetails.find(req.params.userId, (error, detail) => {
        if (error)
            res.send(error);
        res.json(detail);
    }).populate(userId);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use ObjectId

> new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.userId)

```
function getUserDetailByUserId(req, res) {

    userDetails.findOne({userId: new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.userId)})
    .populate(userId)
    .exec(function(error, detail){
        if (error)res.send(error);
        res.json(detail);
    });

}
```

userDetail Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userDetailSchema = new Schema({
  dateOfBirth: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  interest: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  remarks: {
    type: String,
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  // Referencing the Registered Users in User Model by their ObjectId reference.
    ref: 'User'           // Creating a relation between User and UserDetails Model through unique ObjectId.
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserDetails', userDetailSchema);
```

Comment: still i am not getting the data

Comment: still not  getting

Comment: please provide your user detail model schema

Comment: use global.userDetails =require('userDetail .. schma path here'); in your app.js

Comment: Your model is not required properly , so your not able to access your userDetails schema

Comment: but i am getting user details when i use user Detail Id

Comment: not getting data , i think the problem is in function only .. Pls help buddy

Comment: @abby: please stop begging. In addition, your updates are not helpful to  Saurabh, who has no new information to go on. You are the eyes and ears on the problem, so readers are at your mercy. Tell us what does not work, investigate it, show us what you do get, show us errors you get, and so forth. Be as helpful as possible to people who are helping you.